# Connect mongo shell to restricted MongoDB Atlas Database?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I've removed localhost in network connections from a MongoDB Atlas project.

Now my mongo shell can't connect to the MongoDB collection. Other than adding localhost back to network connections, is there any other way to connect to a MongoDB collection? I'd like to poke around the production database sometimes from the CLI, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use VPC peering to connect.